# Why the output is infinite?

Tags: c++, c, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
int i;
while(i=10)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=i+1;
}
```

There is a program in which while(i=10) means while(1)[usually] means the while loop is true.So it should print 10 only once and increment the value of  i by 1 i.e i becomes 11.but the output is infinite printing ‘10’ repeatedly.Why is this so?
My Platform is : 64 bit Windows 7 and working on 32 bit Dev C++ compiler.

Comment: `while (i=10)` is an assignment. `i < 10`  and initialise `i`.

Comment: in next iteration , value of i is again changed to 10 and loop condition becomes true and hence it continues infinitely.

Comment: *A bright young coder named Lee / Wished to loop while `i` was 3 / But when writing the `=` / He forgot its sequel / And thus looped infinitely*

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to use a double equal (comparison) instead of the single equal (assignment) in the while condition. You should also initialize the variable i to 10 (otherwise the while block will never be executed).

```
int i=10;
while (i==10)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See in while loop ,

`while(i=10)  // assigns the value 10 to the i which is always true (becuase any non-zero value is true in such a case).`

What you have used is `assignment operator` `=` so the value returned by this assignment is the value of `rvalue` which is `10` and `10` will always be true.

That's why infinite loop.

You should use `while(i == 10)` or `while(i < = 10)` or any comparison operator inside while loop.

Comparison operator results to either `1`(true) or `0`(false).And when in `while(cond)` `cond` is false loop terminates.

Comment: it should print 10 only once.why infinitely?

Comment: Why @SahilGarg ?:  look in each time you modify the value of `i` inside the loop but again in condiotional part of `while` loop you again put the value `10` to `i`. and the same is returned...I think you are not looking my answer . It explains everything. If you don't get it even plz let me know

Comment: I have explained clearly about assignment and comparison. There is no question of doubt

Answer (score 2):

`while(i=10)` sets `i` to `10`, and then checks it, i.e. converts it to `true` or `false`. Only `0` would be `false`, so this becomes `true` every time, and hence loops forever.

I guess you want `while(i==10)`. Double `=` means "check equality". Single `=` means "set the value".

**Edit:** In fact I'm not really sure what you want. If you aren't initialising `i` before the loop, then perhaps you did mean to set it in the condition. In which case, why are you surprised it gets set to `10` every time?

**Edit again:** Ok, so by your comment, you *do* mean to set it in the condition. So you need to understand how that condition is working. What you wrote is effectively this:

```
while ( (bool)(i=10) )
```

This sets `i` to `10`, then converts `10` to a `bool`, which is always `true`. Then in the loop, `i` gets incremented to `11`. Then when it comes back to the top of the loop, it immediately sets `i` back to `10`. So you are effectively doing:

```
set i to 10; <-----\
print i (=> 10);    |
set i to 11;        |
go back to the top; /
```

Comment: i know the condition is wrong.i am assigning 10 to i in the while operator .but why the ans is infinite and i is not incremented to 11 or more why?

Comment: Because you keep setting it to 10.

Answer (score 2):

In your while condition section , you are assigning value to `i` rather than doing comparison

```
 while(i=10)
```

Errors of such type are hard to track as program compiles successfully .
To avoid such errors do comparison in **reverse** order

`while(10==i) or if(10==x`) etc..

in case you mistakenly use `while(10=i)` , the compiler will throw error something like

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
```

saving precious time debugging later.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key thing you are missing is that the condition statement is *executed* every iteration of the loop. So `i=10` is performed (and the resulting reference tested against zero) for every iteration of the loop, not just the first one.

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
int i;
int j = (i=10);
while(j)
{
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=i+1;
    j = (i=10);
}
```

Where `j = (i=10);` is equivalent to `i = 10; j = i;`.

So the steps become:

1. assign `10` to `i`, and assign the value in the resulting reference (`i`) to `j` (assignments return references or pointers by convention).

   if the value is true (which it always is), execute the loop block

   1. call `printf`

      increment `i`

      assign `10` to `i`, and assign the value in the resulting reference (`i`) to `j`.

A while loop testing an assignment can only fail/stop looping if the value returned from the assignment is zero.

In practise, it is bad style to write loops like this, because they look too similar to the very common `while(i==10)` equality check. Sometimes the return value of an assignment is tested when objects are being used, like `while(nextObjPtr = collection.getNextObj())`, because that will fail as soon as `getNextObj` returns a null pointer. Even that, however, would be more clearly written explicitly:

```
while((nextObjPtr = collection.getNextObj()) != nullptr)
```

Or pre-C++11:

```
while((nextObjPtr = collection.getNextObj()) != NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(i=10)
```

the condition is wrong!
Actually it is not a condition!

you should write

```
while(i<10)
```

Comment: It's still a condition. It just evaluates to something different than what `i==10` would.